# Keycloak java client 403 when retrieving role detail

Tags: keycloak

I'm working with keycloak `8.0.1` and it's java client `keycloak-admin-client` library.

this is my `Keycloak` config

```
public Keycloak keycloakClient(AdapterConfig config) {
    return KeycloakBuilder.builder()
            .clientId(config.getResource())
            .clientSecret((String) config.getCredentials().get(CredentialRepresentation.SECRET))
            .grantType(OAuth2Constants.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
            .realm(config.getRealm())
            .serverUrl(config.getAuthServerUrl())
            .build();
}
```

And with this code I'd like to create user and assign him a role

```
final UserRepresentation user = createUserRepresentation(data);
final UsersResource userResource = getRealmResource().users();
try (Response response = userResource.create(user)) {
    if (response.getStatusInfo().getFamily().equals(Response.Status.Family.SUCCESSFUL)) {
        final String userId = response.getLocation().getPath().replaceAll(".*/([^/]+)$", "$1");
        final RolesResource rolesResource = getRealmResource().roles();
        final RoleResource roleResource = rolesResource.get(data.getRole().getRemoteName());
        final RoleRepresentation role = roleResource.toRepresentation();
        userResource.get(userId).roles().realmLevel().add(Collections.singletonList(role));
        return userId;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to create user " + response.getStatusInfo().getReasonPhrase());
    }
}
```

however it fails on line `final RoleRepresentation role = roleResource.toRepresentation();` with message `javax.ws.rs.ForbiddenException: HTTP 403 Forbidden`.

I don't understand why am I getting this error, because my client has assigned all roles from `realm-management` client

```
create-client
impersonation
manage-authorization
manage-clients
manage-events
manage-identity-providers
manage-realm
manage-users
query-clients
query-groups
query-realms
query-users
realm-admin
view-authorization
view-clients
view-events
view-identity-providers
view-realm
view-users
```

Is there some config which am I missing or is it a bug?

Thanks

Comment: There's strange behaviour...after recreating the realm from scratch it started to work :/

Answer (score 1):

I just have the same problem here, while I'm trying to assign roles to an existing user using a service client (using client credentials).

The solution:
Go to Clients > Select "your" client > Go to "**Service Account Roles**" Tab > Select Client Roles : "**realm-management**" and add "**view-realm**" into the assigned roles.

That's it :)